# Android: cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I don't know where I am going wrong with this I am trying to list the ingredients of a recipe in a recyclerView I just can't get the onBindViewHolder to work to matter what I've tried. The adapter code is below as well is the xml Recipe.class. Essentially I need to display the result of Recipe class to the recyclerView.

**Recipe class**

```
public class Recipe extends MainActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ImageView recipeImage;
    TextView descriptionText, courseText, servingsText, costText, caloriesText, methodText;
    RecyclerView listIngredient;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String search_name;
    Cursor c;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapterRecipe;
    List<RecipeList> itemRecipe = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe);
        //search_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
        search_name = "Speedy chicken couscous";

        loadRecipe();
        //recyclerview Recipe
        adapterRecipe = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, itemRecipe);
        listIngredient = findViewById(R.id.listIngredient);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        listIngredient.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        listIngredient.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        listIngredient.setAdapter(adapterRecipe);

    }
    public void loadRecipe() {
        itemRecipe.clear();
        db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
        String RECIPE_SEARCH = " SELECT A.recipe, A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description " +
                "FROM " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_QUANTITY + " AS A JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_INGREDIENTS +
                " AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name";
        String selectQuery = "";
        selectQuery = RECIPE_SEARCH + " WHERE A.recipe LIKE ?";
        c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RecipeList recipeList = new RecipeList();
                recipeList.setRecipe(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("recipe")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_amount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ingredient_quantity")));
                recipeList.setMeasurement_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("measurement_name")));
                recipeList.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name")));
                recipeList.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("description")));
                itemRecipe.add(recipeList);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }

    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listIngredient"
    android:name="com.stu54259.plan2cook.Recipe"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/caloriesText"
    tools:context=".Recipe"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**Adapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<RecipeList> itemRecipe;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

// data is passed into the constructor
RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<RecipeList> data) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.itemRecipe = data;
}

// inflates the row layout from xml when needed
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

// binds the data to the TextView in each row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.myTextView.setText(itemRecipe.get(position));

}

// total number of rows
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemRecipe.size();
}


// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView myTextView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIngredient);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}


// allows clicks events to be caught
void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

**Full logcat**

```
2020-09-17 13:21:35.570 15862-15862/? E/54259.plan2coo: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-09-17 13:21:50.653 15862-15862/com.stu54259.plan2cook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.stu54259.plan2cook, PID: 15862
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.RecipeList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
        at com.stu54259.plan2cook.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:37)
        at com.stu54259.plan2cook.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:15)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1762)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:779)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2590)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2020-09-17 13:21:50.653 15862-15862/com.stu54259.plan2cook E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**RecipeList model**
public class RecipeList {

```
    private Integer id;
    private Double ingredient_quantity;
    private String recipe;
    private String measurement_name;
    private String ingredient_name;
    private String description;
    private String ingredient_amount = String.valueOf(ingredient_quantity);
    public RecipeList(){

    }

    public RecipeList(String recipe, String ingredient_amount, String measurement_name, String ingredient_name, String description) {

        this.recipe = recipe;
        this.ingredient_amount = ingredient_amount;
        this.measurement_name = measurement_name;
        this.ingredient_name = ingredient_name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getRecipe() {
        return recipe;
    }

    public void setRecipe(String recipe) {
        this.recipe = recipe;
    }

    public String getIngredient_amount() {
        return ingredient_amount;
    }

    public void setIngredient_amount(String ingredient_amount) {
        this.ingredient_amount = ingredient_amount;
    }

    public String getMeasurement_name() {
        return measurement_name;
    }

    public void setMeasurement_name(String measurement_name) {
        this.measurement_name = measurement_name;
    }

    public String getIngredient_name() {
        return ingredient_name;
    }

    public void setIngredient_name(String ingredient_name) {
        this.ingredient_name = ingredient_name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**Updated error**

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

On this line:
holder.myTextView.setText(itemRecipe.get(position).toString());

Comment: post the error log with question.

Comment: Take some time to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code `itemRecipe.get(position)` is returning `RecipeList`  this object you are passing RecipeList directly in to setText where setText expects String, Try to pass the String value here `holder.myTextView.setText(//pass string)`

to pass RecipeList as String Override toString in RecipeList

ex: Here added sample format and included all the variables in toString.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RecipeList{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", ingredient_quantity=" + ingredient_quantity +
            ", recipe='" + recipe + '\'' +
            ", measurement_name='" + measurement_name + '\'' +
            ", ingredient_name='" + ingredient_name + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", ingredient_amount='" + ingredient_amount + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

call toString on RecipeList object in setText

ex:

```
holder.myTextView.setText(itemRecipe.get(position).toString)
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I put the string value here?

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion and I get this "Cannot resolve symbol 'toString'". I put the  toString method in the RecipeList model

Comment: I did that into the RecipeList.class

Comment: This solution worked to correct the issue I had, now I am faced with it doing nothing, just stops running.